# Definition of Sequence Convergence Doesn't Make Sense

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

In real analysis, the convergence of a sequence is defined as follows:

[image]

The statement that $|a_n - a|<\varepsilon$ means that the range is $[a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon]$, where $\varepsilon>0$. Which makes perfect sense.

What doesn't make sense to me is the constraint that $n>N$ (which I've also seen as $n\geq N$). If $n$ only has a lower bound, then there should exist an $n>N$ such that $|a_n-a|>\varepsilon$, which means that it cannot apply to all $n>N$ like the definition says. Note that the total span of the range is only $(a+\varepsilon)-(a-\varepsilon)=2\varepsilon$

The epsilon-delta definition of the limit seems to be an extension of this definition with more constraints, but I'm really confused about how something like this that seems so obvious to me has made it's way into textbooks. Am I missing something super obvious here?

Comment: Why should $|a_n - a|$ be greater than $\epsilon$?

Comment: The definition of convergence means that there is an $N$ such that for any $n>N$ we have $|a_n - a|<\epsilon $

Comment: "If $n$ only has a lower bound, then there should exist an $n>N$ such that $|a_n-a|>\epsilon$". Why is this true?

Comment: You really haven't made your meaning clear. At any rate you're certainly missing something.

Comment: @Andrew Paul - because 'a' is an infinite sequence, 'n' is an index into that sequence, and there is a finite range of a_n that maps to [a-e, a+e] as expressed by |a_n-a|<e. The rule is only that n>N, then at some point, the value at  a_n is beyond a+e. Which means that the claim that |a_n-a|<e for all n>N must be untrue.

Comment: _Why_ do you think that "at some point the value at $a_n$ is beyond $a+\varepsilon$"? There's no reason that claim has to be true.

Comment: @Bitskit I have no idea what "rule" you are alluding to, but what you have described is not the correct definition of the limit of a sequence. If the limit is $a$, then for all indices $n$ large enough ($n>N$), we have that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$. In particular, this means that $a_n$ is precisely in the the interval $(a_n-\epsilon,a_n+\epsilon)$ _for all indices larger than $N$_. There is no condition whatsoever that the inequality only holds for finitely many indices, and the idea of a limit wouldn't even make sense if that was the case.

Comment: Perhaps an example would help? Suppose our sequence is $a_n = 2 + \frac3n$. Then someone picks $\varepsilon = 0.01$. We can now confidently promise him: Whenever $n>301$ it will be true that $|a_n-2|<0.01$. No matter how much larger than $301$ our $n$ gets, it will never be the case that $2+\frac3n > 2.01$.

Comment: @Troposphere Show me a counterexample then, because I don't see how any it can be the case that an n>N can never result in an a_n > a+e.

Comment: The comment just above yours shows a sequence where no matter how large $n$ gets, as long as $n>301$ we will always have $1.99 < a_n < 2.01$.

Comment: I suspect you might somehow be misunderstanding what "a real sequence" can be.

Comment: @Troposphere ah, I think I see what you're saying now. I was getting tripped up over the fact that n was being used as an index and trying to understand the rule in the context of a divergence sequence. In a divergence sequence, there *does* exist an n>0 such that |a_n-a|>=e.

Comment: @Bitskit, yes -- exactly because a _divergent_ sequence means one that _doesn't_ converge to any limit.

Comment: This may help: A sequence $(a_n)$ does not converge to $a$ if $\exists \, \epsilon > 0$ such that for $\forall \, N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists \, n> N$ for which $\left|a_n - a\right| ≥\epsilon$. So should you find such an $n>N$ for any $N$, however large for which $|a_n-a| \nless \epsilon$ or equivalently $|a_n-a| ≥\epsilon$, then your sequence $(a_n)$ sure as hell does not converge to $a$.

Comment: *for all* $n$ greater than *some* $N$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we try looking at the meaning of the definition as applied to an example.

Here is a sequence that approaches $3{:}$
$$
\begin{array}{lclcc}
3+0.1 & \to & 3-0.1 \\
& \swarrow \\
3+0.01 & \to & 3-0.01 \\
& \swarrow \\
3+0.001 & \to & 3-0.001 \\
& \swarrow \\
3+0.0001 & \to & 3-0.0001 \\
& \swarrow \\ & \vdots
\end{array}
$$

Suppose $\varepsilon=0.0000002.$

When $n=13$ and $n=14$ we have this:
$$
\begin{array}{lclcc}
& \swarrow \\
3+0.0000001 & \to & 3-0.0000001 \\
& \swarrow
\end{array}
$$
These numbers differ from $3$ by less than $\varepsilon,$ and so do all of the ones in the sequence that come after them. Thus the term of the sequence differs from $3$ by less than $\varepsilon$ whenever $n\ge13.$

So we have (capital) $N=13.$ And then whenever $n\ge N,$ we have $|a_n - a|<\varepsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

I don’t quite get the question here.

The definition of convergence is defined such that for any epsilon (error) given, we could always find a starting point that these points afterward would fall within the error interval.

On the other hand, with this notion in mind it is then obvious that the starting point would definitely depends on your given error.

Answer (score 0):

$|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ means $a_n$ lies in open set $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$, not closed set as you have mentioned.

And the choice of the $N$-th term depends on the choice of epsilon, and thus it's neccesary.